# Inconsistent key size and plot margins in Gnuplot

Tags: key, gnuplot, margins

I am attempting to generate a plot with a large top margin, and in that margin space place a large key.

According to the *Gnuplot 5.2 Documentation*:

```
set tmargin {{at screen} <margin>}
```

> The **margin** is the distance between the plot border and the outer edge of the canvas

and

> ... screen specifies the screen area (the entire area - not just the portion selected by **set size**), with 0,0 at the bottom left and 1,1 at the top right.

However, when I run the following script,

```
reset
set terminal pngcairo font '12,'
set key on tmargin
N = 15
M = 20
do for [m=2:(M-2)] {
this_margin = m/(0.0 + M)
#print this_margin
set tmargin at screen this_margin
set title sprintf("set tmargin at screen %0.2f",this_margin)
set output sprintf("margin_test_%02i.png", m)
plot for [i=0:N] cos(i*x) title sprintf("cos(%2ix)",i)
}
```

I generate the following animation:
[image: animation]

This animation shows that when the margin is large (i.e. `set margin at screen 0.15`), the key fails to fill the margin, instead it is squished into the top margin space. Only when the margin is small (i.e. `set margin at screen 0.80`) is the key allowed to drop down to a single column. Isn't this behavior backwards?

#### My Question:

How do I get a large top margin (i.e. `set tmargin at screen 0.20` like the beginning plot in the animation) **without** having gnuplot squish a tmargin key up into the top of the canvas?

Note that simply setting the key location manually (e.g. `set key at x,y maxcols 1`) does not fix the squashed key for large margins.

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish? By default, gnuplot is trying to fit the legend inside the plot window. Are you perhaps looking for `set key above right maxcols 1`?

Comment: I am trying to produce a large top margin and have a long key placed into that top margin. Question edited for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `set key above maxcols 1` will give you the desired legend:

```
this_margin = 0.2
set tmargin at screen this_margin
set key on above maxcols 1
set title sprintf("set tmargin at screen %0.2f",this_margin)
plot for [i=0:15] cos(i*x) title sprintf("cos(%2ix)",i)
```

[image]